# get index from watched array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue application where I watch an array for changes. This is working fine. But I'm not sure how to get the index of the array item which has changed, as the watch callback only passes in the old/new values.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3zd4fmv/

Simplified Example:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
  data: {
    things: [{foo:1}, {foo:2}]
  },
  watch: {
    things: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        alert('a thing changed')
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: function () {
        this.things[0].foo = 5
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: vue doesn't watch arrays for changed indices since it's a reference. If you need to get the index, wrap the array in a proxy and call a function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a built in functionality for this, as the use case seems a bit odd. Would you mind fully explaining your intention? As far as I see, you already got the index you're interested in in your `change` method, why not store/use that?

Comment: hi @GMaiolo the change method is a hard coded index key for demo purposes. 
I have a table with a lot of columns and a lot of rows. This table is generated by looping through an array. If I bind a change even to every cell in every row the page load is very slow. Yet If i watch for changes, with binding a change event the page loads very fast. My watch demo works great, I just can't get the index :(

Comment: hi @zfrisch I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm fairly new to vue

Comment: Could you show a bit about how and when the array gets changed?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not out of the box. Using a combination of argument destructuring and [a custom watch function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch), you can achieve something that should do it. For example;

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
  data: {
    things: [{foo:1}, {foo:2}]
  },
  methods: {
    change: function (...args) {
        let [thing, after, before] = args;
        
        console.log(thing);
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.things.forEach(thing => {
      this.$watch(() => thing, this.change.bind(null, thing))
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: If we ever push/pop from the `things` array this will not work properly

Comment: Not exactly like this. But thankfully, you can dynamically add these watchers to new array elements. I use it for a dynamic product list - when a new product is added to the list, I apply the watcher.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for something with less maintenance. It's a real shame more data about the changed item isn't passed to the watcher.